# Communicating with a Node.js process from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to start and communicate with a Node.js process from Python. I've tried using `subprocess` and it keeps hanging on `out = p.stdout.readline()`

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["node"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
msg = "console.log('this is a test');"
p.stdin.write(msg.encode("utf-8"))
p.stdin.write(b"\n")
p.stdin.flush()
out = p.stdout.readline()
print(out)
```

I've used very similar code previously in order to run shell scripts successfully. I've also checked for running `node` processes using `ps` while the above Python script was hanging and it I could see it running. Finally, I've managed to get a valid response via `Popen.communicate()` instead of `readline()` but I need to keep the process running for further interaction.

Can someone please advise on how do I spawn and communicate with a Node.js process from Python? It doesn't necessarily need to use `subprocess`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to mention but after a few days I found out that all I needed was `-i` flag to Node so that it enters the REPL anyway. From `node -h`:

```
-i, --interactive        always enter the REPL even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal
```

So the code will now look like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["node", "-i"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

Marking this one as accepted as it doesn't rely on any third party packages.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you work with the higher level [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) package, instead of the low level stdin /stdout of subprocess.

```
import pexpect
msg = "console.log('this is a test');"
child = pexpect.spawn('node')
child.expect('.*')
child.sendline(msg)
...
```